# Complex binding situation

Tags: java, binding, javafx-8

In a javafx scene I have:

- A combobox with some locales as items
- A hashtable with entries (Locale, String)
- A textfield to show and edit text

[image]

What I want to do is:

- When locale combobox change, textield show the text stored in the hashtable according to locate selected. Example 1: if frech is selected, textfield shows 'french text'. Example 2: if chinese is selected, textfield doesn't show anything (hashtable doesn't contains zh key).
- As some text is being typed in textfield, hashtable execute a put with the locale selected in combobox. Example 1: if 'aaa' is typed and french is selected, hashtable modify the entry fr with the text 'aaa'. Example 2: if 'bbb' is typed and chinese is selected, hastable add the entry (zh,'bbb'). Example 3: if textfiled has no text and english is selected, hashtable removes en entry.

Initially hashtable haven't empty strings and combobox always have a locate selected. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Binding you can do between Properties, since `Hashtable` isn't a `javafx.beans.property.Property` how would you like to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a `String` object in your `Hashtable` you cannot use any `Property`'s binding method to interact with it, but you should still be able to accomplish your goal by using listeners on these properties.  Here is a rough example:

```
public class Controller {

    private VBox base = new VBox();
    private ComboBox<Locale> comboBox = new ComboBox<>();
    private TextField textField = new TextField();
    private Button button = new Button("Print");

    private Hashtable<Locale, String> map = new Hashtable<>();

    public VBox getBase() {
        return base;
    }

    public Controller() {
        setupUi();

        addItem("Chinese");
        addItem("French");
        addItem("English");
        comboBox.getItems().add(new Locale("Russia", "Some Russian Text"));

        comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty()
                .addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> textField.setText(map.get(newVal)));

        textField.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldVal, newVal) -> {
            if (newVal == null || newVal.equals("")) {
                map.remove(comboBox.getValue());
            } else {
                map.put(comboBox.getValue(), newVal);
            }
        });

        comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
    }

    private void setupUi() {
        base.getChildren().addAll(comboBox, textField, button);
        button.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println(map));
    }

    private void addItem(String name) {
        Locale locale = new Locale(name, String.format("Some %s text", name));
        map.put(locale, locale.text);
        comboBox.getItems().add(locale);
    }

}


class Locale {

    String name;
    String text;

    Locale(String name, String text) {
        this.name = name;
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

}
```